# listbox not populating correctly

Tags: c++, winapi, listbox

This is my first posting here, i am trying to learn to program a win32 GUI in code blocks 12.11, but here is the problem,

I have got 2x list boxes on a dialog box window(IDC_LISTP > Personal Project Notes) and (IDC_LISTS > Shared Project Notes),

The (personal project notes) auto populates on the dialog been created, i can also get the (Shared project notes) to populate from the correct folder too(update shared).

The problem arises when i click the button(update personal) after clicking the(update shared ), it loads the contents of (shared project notes) into the(personal project notes) list box, even after using the clear button too, this still populates (the personal project notes) when clicking the (update personal)button,

how do i stop from this from happening???

please could someone help me resolve this problem, has i have been banging my head against a wall for days now,

This is the code i have been currently experimenting with, please excuse the messy code, as most of it is from examples that i have converted to suit my GUI.

additional posts  http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?540733-win32-listbox-not-populating-right with pics too

```
 BOOL CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
            switch(Message){
                case WM_INITDIALOG:
                CheckRadioButton(HWND (hwnd),IDRADIO, IDRADIO2, IDRADIO);
                {
                DlgDirList(HWND (ID_PROJECT_PROJECT_NOTES), pbuffer, IDC_LISTP, 0, DDL_EXCLUSIVE);
                HWND hListBox = GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_LISTP);
                SendMessage(hListBox, LB_DIR, 0, (LPARAM)("*.txt*"));
                }
            break;
                case WM_COMMAND:
                    switch(LOWORD(wParam)){
                        case ID_UPDATEP:{
                        SendDlgItemMessage(HWND(hwnd), IDC_LISTP, LB_RESETCONTENT, 0, 0);
                        DlgDirList(HWND (ID_PROJECT_PROJECT_NOTES), pbuffer, IDC_LISTP, 0, DDL_EXCLUSIVE);
                        HWND hListBox = GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_LISTP);
                        SendMessage(hListBox, LB_DIR, 0, (LPARAM)("*.txt"));

                        }
                        break;
                        case ID_UPDATES:{
                        SendDlgItemMessage(HWND(hwnd), IDC_LISTS, LB_RESETCONTENT, 0, 0);
                        DlgDirList(HWND (ID_PROJECT_PROJECT_NOTES), sbuffer, IDC_LISTS, 0, DDL_EXCLUSIVE);
                        HWND hList = GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_LISTS);
                        SendMessage(hList, LB_DIR, 0, (LPARAM)("*.txt"));

                        }
                        break;
                        case IDCLEAR:
                        SendDlgItemMessage(HWND(hwnd), IDC_LISTP, LB_RESETCONTENT, 0, 0);
                        SendDlgItemMessage(HWND(hwnd), IDC_LISTS, LB_RESETCONTENT, 0, 0);

                            break;
                        case IDCREATE:{
                        DialogBox(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDPAD), NULL, DlgProc);
                        }
                            break;

                        case IDOK:
                        EndDialog(hwnd, IDOK);
                        break;
                        case IDCANCEL:
                        EndDialog(hwnd, IDCANCEL);
                        break;
                    }
                    break;

                case WM_CLOSE:
                    EndDialog(hwnd, 0);
                break;
                default:

                    return FALSE;
            }
            return TRUE;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with your code, take a look at the [MSDN Docs for DlgDirList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761366%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

a) The first parameter to `DlgDirList()` needs to be the `handle to the dialog box that contains the list box`; there is no error checking in the code, I suspect that the call to `DlgDirList()` fails with an error

b) the docs say that `DlgDirList sends the LB_RESETCONTENT and LB_DIR messages to the list box`

So all you need to do is

```
int nResult;
nResult = DlgDirList(hwnd, pbuffer, IDC_LISTP, 0, 0);
TRACE("Filling P (ID %d) from %s: result = %d\n", IDC_LISTP, pbuffer, nResult);
nResult = DlgDirList(hwnd, sbuffer, IDC_LISTS, 0, 0);
TRACE("Filling S (ID %d) from %s: result = %d\n", IDC_LISTS, sbuffer, nResult);
```

Make sure that `pbuffer` and `sbuffer` each contain a path and a wildcard-string, like "C:\personal\*.txt" and "C:\shared\*.txt".

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) contains a sample of how to use `DlgDirList`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply friend, i have altered my code as you advised, the same problem arises thou, after clicking the(update shared button) then clicking the(update personal button) the personal list gets populated with the shared list. these are the pbuffer and sbuffer, [code]char pbuffer[MAX_PATH] = "C:\\Users\\uncboog\\Documents\\Nexum Core\\Project Notepad\\User\\*.txt";
char sbuffer[MAX_PATH] = "C:\\Users\\uncboog\\Documents\\Nexum Core\\Project Notepad\\Shared\\*.txt";[/code] were am i going wrong???, and were would i include the error message within the code, thanks again :)

Comment: my original post as links to another post made by me with pics to show the output  http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?540733-win32-listbox-not-populating-right

Comment: added extra code for `TRACE`, you can also place a breakpoint on the lines and inspect the values

Comment: after altering code[code]case ID_UPDATEP:
                nResult = DlgDirList(hwnd, pbuffer, IDC_LISTP, 0, 0);
                TRACE("Filling P (ID %d) from %s: result = %d\n", IDC_LISTP, pbuffer, nResult);
                    break;[/code], i get multiple warnings, C:\Users\uncboog\Documents\Nexum Core\main.cpp|112|warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value], C:\Users\uncboog\Documents\Nexum Core\main.cpp|112|warning: right operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value] and same problem persists

Comment: would i need to add a sendmessage call after the trace line of code to see the values or could i include some sort of error message, this is my frist ever attempt at a GUI, so plz be gentle, :)

Comment: I'm not very sure why the`TRACE` does not work, you could try replacing it with `char szTrace[1024]; sprintf(szTrace, "Filling P (ID %d) from %s: result = %d\n", IDC_LISTP, pbuffer, nResult); MessageBox(hwnd, szTrace, "Personal", MB_OK);`, ditto for <shared> or place a breakpoint on the lines and inspect the values manually

Comment: Again thank you friend, ok all warnings gone, and the message box return helped, as it is definitely loading from the different folders.filling P(ID3000)from*.TXT: result = 0, same for: filling S(ID3001)from*.TXT: result = 0, so from msdn docs, this is failing even though it is loading the right data to the list boxes to start with, now i am totally lost.:(

Comment: if both are returning 0, then these must be wrong???char pbuffer[MAX_PATH] = "C:\\Users\\uncboog\\Documents\\Nexum Core\\Project Notepad\\User\\*.TXT";both are same except for User is Shared, do i have the formatting right???

Comment: after blocking the //DlgDirList(hwnd, pbuffer, IDC_LISTP, 0, 0); from the case WM_INITDIALOG: the messagebox reads, .filling "C:\\Users\\uncboog\\Documents\\Nexum Core\\Project Notepad\\User\*.TXT": result = 0, same goes for the shared, this is why i am thinking i have the formating wrong???

Comment: shouldn't that be "C:\\Users\\uncboog\\Documents\\Nexum Core\\Project Notepad\\User\\*.TXT"? Why don't you create a fresh new project with just one list box where you type the path-string into an edit control?